# Equi-coercivity of functionals on a metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, metric-spaces

**Definition:** A family of functionals $\{F_n\}$ on a metric space $X$ is said to be equi-coercive if, for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a compact set $K_\alpha$ of $X$ such that for all $n$
we have
$$\{F_n \leq \alpha\} \subseteq K_\alpha.$$

Question:

If $\{F_n\}$ is a family of equi-coercive functionals, How to show there is a non-empty compact set $K$(independent of $n$) such that
$$\inf_{x \in X} F_n(x) = \inf_{x \in K} F_n(x) $$
for all $n$.

Comment: Isn't the result false or missing hypotheses ? Look at the family of functions $f_n(x) = |x - n| + n$. Take $K_{\alpha} = \emptyset$ if $\alpha < 0$ or $K_{\alpha} = [- \alpha, \alpha]$ otherwise. It satisfies your definition of equi-coercivity. However, the infimum of $f_n$ will be grossly overestimated on any fixed compact when $n$ is big.

Comment: A corresponding post on [mathoverflow.se]: [Equi-coercivity of functionals on a metric space](https://mathoverflow.net/q/463511).

Comment: Please do not create new tags without running it by the community, first:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35451/ .

Answer (score -1):

Set $\alpha= \inf\limits_{x\in X}F_1(x)+1$ if $\inf\limits_{x\in X}F_1(x)>-\infty$ or else set $\alpha=0$. Note that $\emptyset\neq \{F_1\leq \alpha\}$. Therefore, by equi-coercivity of $\{F_n\}$, there exists a non-empty compact set $K$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{n\geq 1}\{F_n\leq \alpha\}\subseteq K$. We, therefore, conclude that $\inf\limits_{x\in K}F_n(x)\leq \alpha\leq \inf\limits_{x\in K^c}F_n(x)$ for all $n$. In particular, this implies that $\inf\limits_{x\in K}F_n(x)\leq \inf\limits_{x\in X}F_n(x)$ for all $n$. On the other hand, $\inf\limits_{x\in X}F_n(x)\leq \inf\limits_{x\in K}F_n(x)$ for all $n$ since $K\subseteq X$. It follows that $\inf\limits_{x\in X}F_n(x)=\inf\limits_{x\in K}F_n(x)$

Comment: How do you show that $\inf\limits_{x\in K}F_n(x)\leq \alpha$ for all $n$?